# Inheritence of a JButton Java - Overriding Method Issue

Tags: java, swing, inheritance

I am wanting to set the visibility of a JButton to false in another class. So what I am doing is overriding the boolean function I created in `StudentAccount` named `getWriteBtnVisibility()` to change the visibility of the button in the `HW` class. **So basically I want to make the JButton invisible in the `StudentAccount`.** Since I want that button to be visible when a different type of account is logged in. 
However, the way I am doing it seems not to be working. I have debugged my code and not understanding why it is **not overriding the function**. If I can get some guidance, I'd greatly appreciate it.

`StudentAccount`:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;


public class StudentAccount extends AccountTemplate {


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */


    @Override
    public String getHomeworkBtnName() {
        return "Submit Assignment";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getWriteBtnVisibility() {
        return false;
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    StudentAccount window = new StudentAccount();
                    window.frmAccountTemplate.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

}

`AccountTemplate`:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class AccountTemplate extends HW {

    protected JFrame frmAccountTemplate;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public String getHomeworkBtnName() {
        return "Hw";
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AccountTemplate window = new AccountTemplate();
                    window.frmAccountTemplate.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public AccountTemplate() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    protected void initialize() {
        frmAccountTemplate = new JFrame();
        frmAccountTemplate.setTitle(getFrameTitleName());
        frmAccountTemplate.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frmAccountTemplate.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmAccountTemplate.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnAssignment = new JButton(getHomeworkBtnName());
        btnAssignment.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frmAccountTemplate.dispose();

                HW.main(null);
            }
        });

        btnAssignment.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnAssignment.setBounds(15, 51, 200, 29);
        frmAccountTemplate.getContentPane().add(btnAssignment);



    }

}
```

`HW`:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class HW {

    public JFrame frmHw;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public boolean getWriteBtnVisibility() {
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    HW window = new HW();
                    window.frmHw.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public HW() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    protected void initialize() {
        frmHw = new JFrame();
        frmHw.setTitle("HW");
        frmHw.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frmHw.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmHw.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JTextArea jTextArea1 = new JTextArea();
        jTextArea1.setBounds(9, 11, 328, 197);
        frmHw.getContentPane().add(jTextArea1);

        JScrollPane scrollBar = new JScrollPane(jTextArea1);
        scrollBar.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollBar.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        frmHw.getContentPane().add(scrollBar);
        scrollBar.setBounds(13, 39, 413, 189);


        JButton btnWriteText = new JButton("Write Text");
        btnWriteText.setVisible(getWriteBtnVisibility());
        btnWriteText.setBounds(154, 11, 115, 24);
        frmHw.getContentPane().add(btnWriteText);   

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some insight into **what** you're trying to do, and not just **how** you're trying to do it.

Comment: Probably better to call `button.setEnabled(false);`. Or if constructed from an `Action`, `action.setEnabled(false);`.

Comment: @Jason So when a student is logged in into the GUI application, they are promoted to a GUI window that has the button "Submit Assignment". Once that button is clicked, I want the "Write Text" button to be hidden, that is being called in the `HW` class. However, the "Write Text" button is not hidden.

Comment: @simpleCoder There is no **Submit assignment** button. Have you tried to implement this? Is this already existing but under a different name?

Comment: @Jason I apologize, I forgot to include the @Override function inside of `StudentAccount` that is overriding the name of the JButton inside of `AccountTemplate`. Please see modified post.

Answer (score 1):

When you made AccountTemplate extend the HW class, every method that was redefined in AccountTemplate overrided the original method from HW. The getWriteBtnVisibility is checked from within the HW's initialize method, but AccountTemplate's initialize method overrides it. Now StudentAccount inherits the overridden method which does not check for the getWriteBtnVisibility boolean and so the visibility is not modified.

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do is to extend the layout using inheritance, however to do that you need to create seperate methods that create and initialize the interface components and call them as required from class. Now you've only created a seperate method for the button name and visibility, but the method that checks for the visibility boolean has been overridden and no longer gets called.

You will have to redesign your architecture so that:

- There is only one JFrame field (unless you want multiple interfaces)
- There is only one method that creates the JFrame and sets up the title
- All generic interface components are created using a seperate (final) method and can be called when required by the class that inherits it

A simple example

```
class HW {
  public JFrame frame;

  public String getFrameName() {
    return "HW";
  }

  public boolean getHWBtnVisibility {return true;}

  void setupHWComponents() {
    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    // ...
    this.frame.getContentPane().add(field);

    JButton button = new JButton("HW");
    button.setVisible(getHWBtnVisibility());
    // ...
   }


  void initFrame() {
    this.frame = new JFrame(getFrameName());
    // ....
   }

  void initialize() {
    initFrame();
    setupHWComponents();
  }
}
```

And

```
class AccountTemplate {
   public void setupTemplateComponents() {
     JTextField loginField = new JTextField("login");
     super.frame.getContentPane().add(loginField);
     // ...
    }

   @Override
   public void initialize() {
     // Setup Frame and HW components
     // If you dont want HW components, replace with initFrame()
     super.initialize(); 
     setupTemplateComponents();
   }
}
```

Then the StudentAccount class can likewise choose what components to use and initialize and which ones it doesn't want and then it can add its own components to the frame.

Answer (score 0):

The initialize method that matters, that sets the button's visibility is the one that is called from the HW class, and that method is only called from within AccountTemplate's button's ActionListener here:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    frmAccountTemplate.dispose();
    HW.main(null);
}
```

Notice that it is a call to the `HW` main method, and so it is a HW instance that is being created when this happens (since that is what HW main creates), not a StudentAccount instance. This is why your inheritance doesn't work -- there is no inheritance happening when the button is created.

Having said that, I have to state that this code is overly complex, much more than it needs to be, and misuses inheritance in a way that only serves to confuse. Don't use inheritance (or absolute positioning and null layouts) since you're just complicating things needlessly. Simply your code and you will thank me.

If this were my project,

- I would create distinct JPanels (not JFrames) for each type of GUI
- I would use inheritance only for the program's model, the logical non-GUI aspects of the code, and not for the views (the GUI classes), and would use it very cautiously.
- I would swap views using a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and not swap JFrames